# Laravel - Model attributes stay NULL in database after creation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I have a model named Articles which contained three attributes: 'title', 'subtitle' and 'body' and it worked perfectly but after adding four columns to that model ('subtitle2', 'body2', 'subtitle3' and 'body3') the newly added columns stay NULL after creating articles.
There is clearly something that I missed but I can't figure out what.

This is the migration:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('subtitle2')->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->text('body2')->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->string('subtitle3')->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->text('body3')->nullable()->default(null);
            
        });
    }
```

After migrating I edited my app/Http/Models/Article.php and it looks like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'subtitle',
    'body',
    'subtitle2',
    'body2',
    'subtitle3',
    'body3',

];
```

This is my app/Http/Livewire/CreateArticle.php

```
class CreateArticle extends Component
{
use WithFileUploads;

public $title;
public $subtitle;
public $body;
public $category;

public $subtitle2;
public $body2;

public $subtitle3;
public $body3;

public $temporary_images;
public $images = [];

public $article;
    
    
    public function store()
    {
        $this->validate();

        
        $this->article = Category::find($this->category)->articles()->create($this->validate());
        
        $this->article->user()->associate(Auth::user());
        $this->article->save();
        
        if(count($this->images)){
            foreach($this->images as $image){
                $newImage = $this->article->images()->create(['path'=>$image->store('images', 'public')]);
                
                dispatch(new ResizeImage($newImage->path, 600, 400));
            }
            
        }          
}
```

And finally I added these lines to the form:

```
    {{-- INSERT SUBTITLE 2 --}}
    
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="subtitle2" class="form-label">Second paragraph subtitle</label>
        <input type="text" wire:model="subtitle2" class="form-control" id="subtitle2">
       
    </div>
    
    
    {{-- INSERT PARAGRAPH 2 --}}
    
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="body2" class="form-label">Second paragraph</label><br>
        <textarea class="form-control" wire:model="body2" id="body2" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    
    
    {{-- INSERT SUBTITLE 3 --}}
    
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="subtitle3" class="form-label">Third paragraph subtitle</label>
        <input type="text" wire:model="subtitle3" class="form-control" id="subtitle3">
        
    </div>
    
    
    {{-- INSERT PARAGRAPH 3 --}}
    
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="body3" class="form-label">Third paragraph</label><br>
        <textarea class="form-control" wire:model="body3" id="body3" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
```

[dd($this); is returning the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2JnO.png)

[Tinker is showing all columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boIrV.png)

Comment: For a start, `user_id` is not present in your `$fillable`. [Read the documentation...](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent)

Comment: @Jaquarh 
It is not, but there is a one to many relationship between the User and the Article model that works perfectly.
I added user_id with a migration to the Articles table and I have a function to link Article and User

 ` public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }`

Comment: Is the form sending over the new fields correctly? Like in your store function if you Log `$this->subtitle2` does it show null or the correct value?

Comment: @NotDavid if I put a dd($this->subtitle2); it actually returns me the correct value for subtitle2. But it won't use it to fill the db field anyway. But it's getting weirder than that. I tried to dd($this); and it is showing only the values that won't get stored, while the ones that are actually stored are NULL. I updated the post with the screenshot of the dd.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting, what happens if you dd the result of `$this->validate();`?(looks like you are calling `$this->validate();` twice btw

Comment: @NotDavid dd($this->validate()); gives me an error: "Property [$validate] not found on component: [create-article]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify

```
protected $rules
```

in order to use

```
$this->validate()
```

Comment: What a fool, I had forgotten to add rules for the other attributes! It fixed everything, I couldn't be more grateful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the **dd();** image you provided is the latest. I can see the new columns does not exists in database. **('subtitle2', 'body2', 'subtitle3' and 'body3')** all these are not available in list.
so I think you are missing to run the migrate command

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: The dd(); image is the latest and I actually ran the migration. I added the Tinker image in the post and the columns are all there.

Comment: then you need to select those columns in method where you get data from Articles table for example Article::select('id','body','subtitle2', 'body2', 'subtitle3' and 'body3')->get();

Comment: of course you will need to provide all the columns you need from database